# error - Sorting Array Elements By Frequency

Tags: c++, stl

I want to sort array elements based on frequency but i got some error. please help to rectify my code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

bool comp(pair <int,int> &v1, pair<int,int> &v2){
    if(v1.second == v2.second)
        return v1.first < v2.first;
    return v1.second > v2.second;
}
main(){

    int n,a;
    cin>>n;
    vector < pair<int,int> > v; 
    vector < pair<int,int> >::iterator it;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>a;
        it = find(v.begin(),v.end(),a);
        if(it!=v.end()){
            v[it-v.end()].second++;
        }else{
            v.push_back(make_pair(a,1));
        }
    }

    sort(v.begin(),v.end(),comp);

    for(it=v.begin();it!=v.end();it++){
        int freq = it->second;
        while(freq--){
            cout<<it->first<<" ";   
        }
    }

}
```

Example:

```
Input : arr[] = {2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 12, 2, 3, 3, 3, 12}

Output : 3 3 3 3 2 2 2 12 12 4 5
```

Comment: Instead of `v[it-v.end()].second` (which is wrong btw, you're indexing before the front of the vector) you can just write `it->second`, this is what iterators are for.

Comment: Reading the thing again, this doesn't even compile. Please post code that actually compiles so we can try it.

Comment: @Pezo there is any compilation error, thats the real problem i am facing

Comment: Then say so. Your question makes it seem as though you had the program running (you give an example). Please always include the exact error you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

There are two obvious errors in your code.

As I said in my comment, replace `v[it-v.end()].second` by `it->second`, that's what you're trying to do by indexing I'm assuming.

Second, `std::find` uses `operator==` to compare the value you're looking for with values in the vector. But you can't compare an `int` with a `std::pair<int, int>`. Instead you should be using [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_if) and compare the `int` with `pair.first`.

There's also some little things that are not errors but bad practice: `int n` seems unused; and don't declare `it` way up there, declare it only where you actually need it (also, use `auto` so you don't have to spell out that long name).

Comment: can you provide the correct code as i am still facing errors

Comment: how to compare int with pair.first ?

Comment: Look into lambdas and function objects. There should also be some examples on cppreference (I'm on mobile, so not going to look now).